# C# file path mimic via database

Tags: c#, .net, database, streaming, filepath

Here is a challenge for you - .NET C# 4.0 or below.

I have a basic C# application which has a single button on a form.

The button uses an API which takes a file path as a parameter for the location of an audio file.
The API then allows the calling of the file e.g. someoneElsesAPI.Play("C:\myfile.vox") to play the file.

I do not have control over the API.  I have to use the API - no choice there.

**The problem is, the audio file (.vox) is stored in a database (as a blob).
How do I supply a file name to the API yet provide something that is streamed from the database in order to play the file?**

For example, in ASP.NET one can display an image dynamically by using a handler or aspx page and response outputting as an image.  I want to do the same trick for an audio file in a C# desktop application.

The type of audio file is irrelevant - I need to know how to call a file via a file path which doesn't exist (but does exist as a blob in a database).

hehe I don't ask for much do I?

Mucho thanks.

Best of luck in this challenge!

Dan.

Comment: Your 1st mistake is storing binary data in a database.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with storing binary data in a DB. Not saying that DB is always the way to go, but it is definitly a valid solution for a large number of use cases.

Comment: No "nice" and "clean" solution to solve this. Storing audio-files in the database is just bad design. You should really reconsider this.

Comment: I don't agree with leppie. Maybe that was not his choice, or he had no other choice.

Comment: @Guillaume: nope it is not. The database is not meant to hold that kind of data. And most of the time is just poor design and people just stuffing the files into the database because it's technical possible.

Comment: @Yves M. For all who want a more in depth discussion of DB vs Files, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay Best argument for storing in a DB is when you need transactionality

Comment: Right let me help you all out here - the files are up to 50K in size so they not big so acceptable to be stored in database.  Instead of debating what is good and bad practice, how about answering the question??  Then I'll decide whether the solution is acceptable or too much of a trade off.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that it can be done in any reasonable way. Instead you could easily fetch the blob. Save it to a temporary file and give the path of the temporary file to the API. It will not provide any kind of streaming, but as you can probably imagine, overriding the way .net handles the file system is not something that can easily be done. And why would you? If this is a *real* problem for you, I would recommend changing the API you use to another one that supports what you are trying to achieve instead of looking for *hacky* solutions.

Comment: I am already storing the files as temporary files since that is what the API exposes.  But I don't want to save the file - that's why I am asking.

Comment: Also, as stated in my question - I cannot change the API.  I have no choice but to use the API - so I'm stretching .NET to make the most of what I have.

Answer (score 3):

Read the blob from the database, store the file into a temporary file, then pass the temp file name into the api

Comment: That is what I already do, because currently, thats my only option.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the API opens files, you might be able to use a NamedPipe as a "virtual file".

This command line example creates a named pipe called hello.txt, and writes some "data" to it.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;

namespace TestNamedPipe
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("hello.txt"))
            {
                pipe.WaitForConnection();
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(pipe))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can run "type \\.\pipe\hello.txt" from a command prompt to see how the pipe can be read by some apps as though it were a file. The "file name" will always be "\\.\pipe\" followed by the pipe name.

This doesn't work for all apps or APIs, though. For example "sort.exe \\.\pipe\hello.txt" works, but "more.exe \\.\pipe\hello.txt" doesn't.